# MySQL CONCAT truncates string inside IF THEN block

Tags: mysql, sorting, if-statement, stored-procedures, concatenation

I've got an odd one here--at least odd to me.

I'm working on a fairly simple stored procedure. There are a number of parameters that can be passed into the procedure based on a web form. One of those is a sort order parameter. Records may be sorted by song_title, artist or date_uploaded, but I always want the records returned to be sorted by song_title first. This works just fine if the user chooses song_title or artist to sort by, but it seems to blow up if the user chooses 'date_uploaded'.  I'm using a simple IF...THEN block to evaluate the sort order and modify it accordingly.

Here's the code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spGetAllTracksSong;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE spGetAllTracksSong(IN startRecord INT, IN rowsReturned       INT, IN searchArtist VARCHAR(255), IN searchTitle VARCHAR(244), IN orderBy VARCHAR(20), IN duets TINYINT(1))
BEGIN
    select concat('song_title,',orderBy);

    IF orderBy='date_uploaded' THEN SET orderBy='date_uploaded DESC';END IF;
    select orderBy;
    IF orderBy <> 'song_title' 
        THEN SET orderBy=CONCAT('song_title,',orderBy);
    END IF;
    select orderBy;

    SET @outputSQL=CONCAT('SELECT song_title, artist, disc_number, is_duet, comments
FROM track
WHERE song_title LIKE CONCAT(\'%',searchTitle,'%\')
AND artist LIKE CONCAT(\'%',searchArtist,'%\')
AND is_bad=0
AND is_duet=',duets,' 
ORDER BY ',orderBy ,' 
LIMIT ',startRecord,',', rowsReturned);


    PREPARE stmt FROM @outputSQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;   

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

So, what's happening is that in the block where I attempt to concatenate 'song_title' and whatever is in the orderBy parameter, it's truncating the value of that parameter. So 
    date_uploaded DESC
becomes
    date_uplo

Any thoughts on this? I'm fairly confident that the problem is within the IF THEN block as I've tested the concatenation code and it's producing the results that I want, but I'll be gobsmacked if I can see what's wrong with the syntax.

Comment: `orderBy VARCHAR(20)`; 20 is not some "initial capacity", it is the maximum length.

Comment: You limited your variable to 20 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments pointed out, the problem is the length of the `orderBy` variable. Here's why. It's declared as a maximum of 20 characters.  When it has a value of something other than `song_title`, `orderBy` gets `song_title,` prepended to it.  That string is 11 characters.  Then, `date_uploaded DESC` gets truncated to the first 9 characters, which leaves your order by clause set to `song_title,date_uplo`.

Make the orderBy variable larger by at least another 10 characters and the problem will go away.

Comment: Okay, that worked. I was a tad surprised, as I didn't realize that the length of the parameter would continue expanding after it was passed  to the procedure. Something new learned. Thanks a bunch; this was driving me nuts.

Comment: My apologies. Done.